# Languages with definite and indefinite conjugation

Tags: verbs, list-of-languages, inflection, definiteness

Apart from Hungarian, are there any other languages with definite and indefinite conjugation (verbal inflections)?

For example (in Hugarian):

Definite conjugation:   I see the tree. – Láto**m** a fát.

Indefinite conjugation: I see a tree.   – Láto**k** egy fát.

See more: https://myhunlang.com/2010/02/07/the-difference-between-definite-and-indefinite-conjugation/

**Given user23769's answer below, are there any non-Uralic languages with definite and indefinite conjugation?**

Answer (score 2):

Mordvin is another example of that feature.

Comment: That Mordvin/Erzya it is also an Uralic language is not surprising.

Answer (score 2):

[Inuit languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuit_grammar#Non-specific_verbs) have specific and nonspecific verbs. Specific verbs are used when the direct object is definite, and nonspecific verbs are used in other cases.

However, the relationship between these two categories appears to be lexical.

> Many verbs belong in both categories, and can take either set of endings depending on the type of information about the verb's arguments that speakers intend to communicate. Others are restricted to one category or require a morphological change in order to move between categories.

Comment: Partly lexical, at least. Some verbal roots are inherently definite (only used in ergative constructions with the subject in the ergative case and the object(s) definite and in the plain form), and some are inherently indefinite (only used in accusative constructions with the subject in the plain form and any object(s) present indefinite and in the instrumental case). Most verbs, however, are either used directly in both (e.g., Gl. _takuvoq_ ‘he sees’, _takuvaa_ ‘he sees it’) or use a suffix to more or less predictably switch between definite and indefinite.

Answer (score 0):

Punjabi has indefinite and definite verb conjugations, specifically of the subjunctive forms of verbs. An inflecting suffix ਗਾ (Gurmukhi) / گا (Shamukhi) is used for this.

Indefinite:

میں اُتھے **جاواں**

"I will go there"

Definite:

میں اُتھے **جاؤں‌گا**

"I will surely go there"

English captions are approximate of course

Comment: Can you please provide transcriptions for those who do not read Gurmukhi or Shamukhi? Can you also explain how the Punjabi forms relate to definiteness the same way the Hungarian examples in the question do? From the English translations, the suffix you mention seems rather to express an intensive or desiderative mood than a definite conjugation.

Comment: There is no way to translate these exactly to English; the only reason I used "surely" instead of the "a / the" distinction in the opening post is because Punjabi does not use particles so it would make less sense. It would be more accurate to translate both to "I will go there," but the distinction in meaning still exists in Punjabi just to indicate an additional degree of certainty/specificity/definiteness. They are quite similar to the Hungarian in that they are suffixed verbal conjugations.

Comment: The suffix is "-ga"
Indefinite: "main utthe javan"
Definite: "main utthe javanga"

Comment: I think you mean ‘articles’ rather than ‘particles’. The thing is that what the question is asking about is different conjugations for definite and indefinite _objects_. Neither of your sentences, at least in their English translations, contains an object, since ‘go’ is an almost (though not quite) universally intransitive verb. Can the same effect be applied to a transitive construction; e.g., can adding _-ga_ to the verb turn a sentence that means “He painted a house” into one that means “He painted the house”, referring to a specific house?

Comment: If instead _-ga_ would make it mean something like “He definitely painted a house”, intensifying the certainty that the painting took place, rather than narrowing down the house to a specific one, then that’s a different function, something more along the lines of an intensive or desiderative.

Comment: I meant articles yes, sorry. 

Punjabi has something called verb phases, most intransitive verbs have phases where they become transitive. -ga is called the definite conjugation in _Panjabi: A Comprehensive Grammar_. It is sort of hard to describe exactly the distinction being made in English, I will have to ask somebody else later and see how they would translate it

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have figured it out, the difference in conjugating for a definite object is indicated in a way which can overlap with the definite verbal suffix.
The way you would specify definiteness on the object of the verb would be by breaking gender-number agreement on the suffix, which can be _-ga_, or something else.
"alooan ubalge" = potatoes were boiled
"alooan ubalga" = the potatoes were boiled
_-ge_ here is the masculine plural of _-ga_, alooan is plural masculine "potato." This is how we would change the verb for definite-ness of object.

Comment: Feminine singular would also be used with the masculine singular form of _-ga_ or other suffix to indicate definite-ness of the object. We could say this is a "neuter" definite conjugation or say it is a manifestation of complex verbal agreement rules and mean the same thing. There would be no change for masculine singular though.